# Cannot find direct.h

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

For some reason when I try to compile my code, I get this error:

fatal error: direct.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I'm on linux using g++ (GCC) 4.6.0 20110509 (Red Hat 4.6.0-7)

Comment: Which `direct.h` do you need? One that was written by someone on your team? Or `eglibc-2.12.1/sysdeps/unix/sysv/direct.h` or `linux-2.6/fs/nilfs2/direct.h` or `<linux_headers>/include/config/pci/direct.h` ? What does your `#include` line look like? What does your `Makefile` look like?

Comment: What symbols are you trying to bring in?

Comment: You need to supply more details. Is direct.h one of your own headers or are you trying to use 3rd party libraries?

Comment: @sarnold the line is #include <direct.h> and there's no makefile yet. I didn't work on this part of the code so I'm not sure what he's using the header for but I'm guessing file IO since the code is for an INI reader. Worst case scenario I wait until tomorrow and have him fix it but it makes testing my code harder when his breaks the build.

EDIT: I know it isn't one of our headers, the only library we use is SFML and it isn't a part of that either.

Comment: I bet it's a windows-specific header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`direct.h` is part of the Digital Mars compiler, not gcc.

Most of its functions have similar names on linux that's posix standarized. Read the manpage for e.g. [getcwd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html) , [rmdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rmdir.html), [mkdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) ,or clarify your question as to which functions you need.

As a start, just remove the include and see what other errors you are getting, and work from there.

Comment: Thanks, I looked through his code and changed a few things and now it works fine.

Comment: A direct.h include file is also provided by Microsoft for Windows development.

Answer (score 7):

Commonly,  is a C/C++ header file provided by Microsoft Windows, so it cannot works in linux.

[reference at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct.h)

You can use unistd.h to replace the actions in direct.h like mkdir, rmdir, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I took SWMM5 source code and modify the files following the readme and some small fixes. It seems in linux you do not need direct.h at all for the CLE version. I have tested several of the examples provided by EPA
https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2014-05/epaswmm5_apps_manual.zip

You can get the files [from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SXwdLnLLLYUjFyZnZzdHBOWnM).

Let me know if something is not working.