# direct.h documentation

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems, directory, mingw

I'm trying to write a small block of code that prints out the files in a given directory. I've seen references to using the `direct.h` library to do this, but I cannot find any documentation whatsoever on the header file and its methods. Is this library outdated? And is there another way to list all filenames of a directory in C++?

Comment: The accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193607/cannot-find-direct-h says that direct.h is not part of the gcc compiler so depending on which compiler you are using it might not be available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this header functions are not designed for this task, See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as5kw0ze(v=vs.110).aspx

Use [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) loop like in this [example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`dirent.h` is header which works cross platform. So I would recommend to use it instead of some Windows functions. On some compilers it's not included as a standart header, for example `Visual Studio` but you can use it.