# Batch files commands in C++

Tags: c++, c, batch-file, system

I have a few questions in c++ batch files:

1. I tried to do system("dir c:\ ")  but it always just show the folder of the project, not the C:\ folder.
   why? how can i fix this?
2. Some process in batch (like copy con) require control+c or control+z to stop them. How can I insert such a thing to the batch program from the C++ program?

Comment: If you actually have `system("dir c:\");` in your code, I expect the compiler to reject it. If not, post exactly what you have in your code...

Comment: For your second question, exactly what are you trying to do? Creating a file with some text in it would be much easier using a string constant in C++ and just writing it to a file, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The backslash (`\`) character in C strings is used as an escape character to insert non-printable or otherwise "strange" characters in C strings - you've probably seen e.g. `\n` for the newline character. From this reason, to insert a literal backslash in your string you have to write `\\` (otherwise the compiler may mistake it for an escape sequence).

   In your specific case, the compiler sees the escape sequence `\` , which is not defined as an escape sequence, but many compiler treat undefined escape sequences simply ignoring the backslash; thus, what the batch interpreter actually sees is `dir c:` . Now, the DOS convention is that, if you just write the drive letter followed by colon, without any trailing backslash, you are referring to the current directory on that drive; hence the behavior you are seeing. To fix this, just write

   ```
    system("dir c:\\");
   ```
2. There's no standard functionality for this, although you can use the [_popen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function (clone of the POSIX `popen`) to get something like that.

On the other way, if you are programming in C++ you shouldn't rely on batch that much: just write the code to perform the operations you need directly in C++ and avoid messing with the (horrible) Windows command interpreter.

Comment: thanks! does that mean that every time i use back-slash \ i need to write it as \\ ? and  one more thing: how can i make a batch command sen my C++ program info? for example: i want the string time variable to contain the output of system(time /t) . how can i do this?

Comment: @user2554080: you can use a pipe (e.g. using the function said above), but you should avoid this stuff, use the C++ functions instead! Look up the header `<ctime>`.

Comment: @user2554080: a pipe is a way to communicate with another program you launched; you can create it e.g. with `popen`. But you don't need that: if you want to write a program in C++, write it in C++; if you want to write batch, write a batch file. But don't mix C++ with batch whenever you have to learn something: instead, learn the C++ way to do that.

Comment: the C++ way is a lot more complicated than the batch way..... Does the C++ way works on ALL OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `system("command")` you only execute one command and if you try to execute `system("command2")` the execution conditions are the same as executing first one.

If you want to call some commands you need to use one `system()` call for all of them. I tried this a few years ago but it's not a good idea. Either you can make `mybat.bat` file and execute it using `system("mybat.bat")`

Anyway, I do not recomend use `system()`. [Read this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/).

And about second part of your question. It may be, that you need `PostMessage` but I'm not sure... And this works on Windows only.

Comment: The first two paragraphs, although true, aren't relevant to this situation; also, `PostMessage` is not relevant to console applications (and you cannot use it anyway when using `system`, since it doesn't provide you any `HWND` you can use).

Comment: It looks like using system() function is a bad idea. If so, how can I manege files from a C++ program? Or how can I preform all the other abilities of a batch file?

Comment: @user2554080 It's possible to the same things with c++ without using `system()` calls. It's hard to say, what exact you need because I don't know, what the word _manage_ means in your case. You should use google, after that you may ask as another question, in case if you find nothing.

Comment: I'm having a problem with the command: dir "c:\program files"   how do i give a command like that?

Comment: I'm having a problem with the command: dir "c:\program files"  how do I give a command like that, or a command that has a folder\file name with a space?

Comment: If you still want to use `system()` it would be `system("dir \"C:\\Program files\"")` but I would offer to read about `dirent.h` header and use functions from that.

Comment: It works, thanks! but the dirent.h doesn't exist in microsoft visual studio 2010... so I looked up this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657980/direct-h-documentaion . thing is, I really wish there is some way to use batch programming instead off all those other C++ functions that just make it more complicated. I just want to do a good running-time, effective program.   Is writing to .bat file and the execute it from the C++ program is considered effective?

Comment: I'm not sure if `.bat` execution is effective but it's unsafe so it's better not to use it, if you want, you can check efficiency yourself. Just take nano time at the begining of function and in the end, count difference and compare times using `.bat` files and other possible solutions. Also I added another answer to the question you gave link.